# What are the changes we need to do in order to migrate a spring mvc project from version 2 to version 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

What are the changes we need to do in order to migrate a spring mvc project from version 2 to version 4.

Comment: You can find information in [the official Github repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework).

Answer (score 0):

should be as straightforward . change of version numbers in your Maven POMs. Note that you may have to upgrade specific third-party dependencies to a recent enough version (e.g. Hibernate 3.6+, Quartz 1.8+, Jackson 1.8+, Tiles 2.2+), but other than that, you should be able to get all the benefits of the Spring 4 line with hopefully very little effort.

Comment: I am looking for the changes we need to do by removing the xml based configurations and implement annotations.

Comment: Well in that case . There are a few things you need to remove .  Please refer to this book http://ebook-dl.com/rar/Professional_Java_for_Web_Applications_Nicholas_S_Williams(www.ebook-dl.com).zip .. but FYI xml configurations are scalable and  you can extend it to anywhere . It separates configuration from program logic but annotations doesn't ..